# access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm developing a server application using Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL. I have a problem when trying to connect to the Cloud SQL when running the server on my local machine. I get the error:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

Here is the servlet code:

```
package com.example.example;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Please use the form to POST to this url");
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String url = null;
        try {
            if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
                // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
                url = "jdbc:google:mysql://app_id:instance_id/data?user=root";
            } else {
                // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                url = "jdbc:mysql://instance-ip:3306/data?user=root";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            out.println("Connection established");
            try {
            } finally {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            out.append(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have added the following line to the java.policy file:

> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup";

But this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver instead of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?  Maybe you've got another driver (that uses threads) in the class path?

Comment: I did try the other driver. The problem, as it turns out was that I was using a older version of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, which was apparently using threads.

Comment: Great, glad you fixed it.  I heard of similar issues with some versions of Hibernate and threads.

Comment: I updated my JDBC driver but I keep getting this error. Any idea why?